# Standard form of Quadratic Equation

Tags: definition, quadratics

$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$ is considered the standard form of a quadratic equation. What exactly is the form of an equation? Is the form of the following two quadratic equations the same: 2x^2 - 6 = 0, 2a^2 - 6 = 0. If yes then please explain how. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the degree of the equation.

Comment: I don't support the silent downvote.

Comment: Not an answer, just a personal comment: my favorite form is $ax^2+\color{green}2bx+c=0$, or even better the monic form $x^2+2bx+c=0$, it simplifies some computations.

Comment: "What is exactly is the form of an equation?" doesn't make sense.

Comment: For example $ A x = \dfrac{-C}{x} -B $ is not standard form but can be reduced to the above standard form.

Comment: None of the answers are actually addressing your question. The form of the equation is the **syntactic format** that the equation must be in. Note that if you want to be precise about "form", it is **insufficient** to say "quadratic equation". Rather, you have to specify the variable/indeterminate, such as in "quadratic equation in $x$". The equation "$Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ is a quadratic equation in $x$, but a linear equation in $A$. $2a^2-6=0$ is a quadratic equation **in $a$**, not in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

A 'form' of an equation is a way to write an expression. The standard form of a quadratic is $y=ax^2+bx+c$ because it expresses the coefficients of the powers of $x$. This makes it easy to apply the quadratic formula.

Different forms of quadratics can be useful for different things. For example, the same quadratic can be expressed as $y=a(x-h)^2+k$, where $(h,k)$ is the turning point. Root form is the factorised version of standard form, which is given by $y=(x-a)(x-b)$. Root form clearly indicates the $x$-intercepts of the quadratic. Note that you can rearrange the equation to achieve any of these forms.

This isn't limited to quadratics. Think about cubics, square root functions, inverse relations, and even trigonometric equations have their own standard forms.

Comment: Is the form of the following two quadratic equations the same: 2x^2 - 6 = 0, 2a^2 - 6 = 0. If yes then please explain how. Thanks.

Comment: @B.Han They're of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a=2$ and $c=-6$. So yes, they're in the same form.

Comment: How exactly do two quadratic equations in different variables have the same form?

Answer (score 0):

The standard form of an equation is how it is most commonly expressed, since it is usually easier to deal with and to see properties of it.

For the quadratic equation, the usual/standard form is $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ since we can easily see the coefficients of each power of $x$ and plug them into the quadratic formula. Writing it like $$x^2+\frac ba x+\frac ca=0\quad\text{or}\quad x(ax+b)=-c$$ makes it harder to do this.

This applies to any equation/formula.

For example, the area of a circle is given by $$A=\pi r^2$$ not $$A=\pi\left(\frac d2\right)^2=\frac14\pi d^2$$ since this is more complicated and rather unnecessary.